# Type annotation for partial functions

Tags: python, types, mypy

we have multiple partial-like functions with same type annotation with args and kwargs like:

```
def fruit(fruit_name: str, fruit_class: Type, arg1: int, arg2: float, arg3: tuple):
    pass
    
def apple(*args, **kwargs):
    return fruit("apple", *args, **kwargs)
    
def orange(*args, **kwargs):
    return fruit("orange", *args, **kwargs)
    
def banana(*args, **kwargs):
    return fruit("banana", *args, **kwargs)
```

can I somehow create a template for functions `apple`, `orange`, `banana` and assign it to them?
I thought about `Protocol` with `__call__` definition, but it is unclear how to assign it to functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than a function, you can use `functools.partial`:

```
from typing import Callable, Type
from functools import partial

Fruit = ...  # whatever fruit returns
# type of fruit(), but without the initial string parameter
FruitMaker = Callable[[Type, int, float, tuple], Fruit]

def fruit(fruit_name: str, fruit_class: Type, arg1: int, arg2: float, arg3: tuple) -> Fruit:
    ...


apple: FruitMaker = partial(fruit, "apple")
orange: FruitMaker = partial(fruit, "orange")
banana: FruitMaker = partial(fruit, "banana")
```

Another possibility would be to refactor `fruit` to take a name, and *return* a function that closes over the fruit name.

```
def fruit_maker(fruit_name: str) -> FruitMaker:
    def fruit(fruit_class: Type, arg1: int, arg2: float, arg3: tuple):
        ...
    return fruit

apple = fruit_maker("apple")
orange = fruit_maker("orange")
banana = fruit_maker("banana")
```

Answer (score 0):

The "Builder" pattern may work for you:

```
class Fruit: pass
class FruitBuilder:
    def __init__(self, fruit_name: str):
        pass
    def build(self, fruit_class: type, arg1: int, arg2: float, arg3: tuple) -> Fruit:
        pass

class AppleBuilder(FruitBuilder):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("apple")

class OrangeBuilder(FruitBuilder):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("orange")

AppleBuilder().build(...)
```

Comment: is it possible to go without class ? That is highly undesired

Comment: What you really need is a FruitBuilderBuilder to give you complete customisation over the supply chain.